# CSRF Token Storage by sailsjs

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I am working on enterprise solution using sailsjs as nodejs framework. Security is integral part of implementation. Apart from SSL, CORS, we are also using sailsjs CSRF implementation. I am still evaluating how secure is it to use this token. Can anybody guide on following:
Where sailsjs stores CSRF token? Is it encrypted? How secure is it to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to do some work to validate that your tokens are not accessible to untrusted servers; they should respond only to GET requests, and they should not but accessible via AJAX, nor should CORS headers be enabled.

PillarJS has an [excellent readme on CSRF](https://github.com/pillarjs/understanding-csrf). It says about CSRF tokens:

> CSRF Tokens
>
> Alas, the final solution is using CSRF tokens. How do CSRF tokens
>   work?
>
> Server sends the client a token. Client submits a form with the token.
>   The server rejects the request if the token is invalid. An attacker
>   would have to somehow get the CSRF token from your site, and they
>   would have to use JavaScript to do so. Thus, if your site does not
>   support CORS, then there's no way for the attacker to get the CSRF
>   token, eliminating the threat.
>
> Make sure CSRF tokens can not be accessed with AJAX! Don't create a
>   /csrf route just to grab a token, and especially don't support CORS on
>   that route!
>
> The token just needs to be "unguessable", making it difficult for a
>   attacker to successful within a couple of tries. It does not have to
>   be cryptographically secure. An attack is one or two clicks by an
>   unbeknownst user, not a brute force attack by a server.

Also consider this from [Sails.js docs](http://sailsjs-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/concepts/CSRF/) which gives a real-world example of how they operate:

> CSRF tokens are temporary and session-specific; e.g. Imagine Mary and
>   Muhammad are both shoppers accessing our e-commerce site running on
>   Sails, and CSRF protection is enabled. Let's say that on Monday, Mary
>   and Muhammad both make purchases. In order to do so, our site needed
>   to dispense at least two different CSRF tokens- one for Mary and one
>   for Muhammad. From then on, if our web backend received a request with
>   a missing or incorrect token, that request will be rejected. So now we
>   can rest assured that when Mary navigates away to play online poker,
>   the 3rd party website cannot trick the browser into sending malicious
>   requests to our site using her cookies.

And finally, Sails.js uses the [Connect CSRF protection middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/csrf.html). Tokens are stored on a *per-session* basis, and therefore are not stored in a database nor is (double) encryption needed. Here's another excellent SO answer on the subject: [Why does Express/Connect generate new CSRF token on each request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21645504/why-does-express-connect-generate-new-csrf-token-on-each-request)

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. But please explain where a token is stored throughout session? In application memory? It should be in some data structure in that case.

Comment: Memory yes, in a variable if I remember correctly. If you're looking at how to retrieve tokens, that's also in the documentation.

Comment: [Connect CSRF protection middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/csrf.html) has my answer. Thanks.